# libevent is not found but it's already installed on the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to use libevent-2.1 to use pgbouncer on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have installed successfully with the command:

```
sudo apt install libevent-dev
```

And I can successfully see it with `ldconfig -p | grep libevent`:

```
    libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7
    libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7
    libevent_extra-2.1.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_extra-2.1.so.7
    libevent_core-2.1.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_core-2.1.so.7
    libevent-2.1.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.7
```

But then if I run `pgbouncer` I get this error: `bin/pgbouncer: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.1.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Any idea how to fix this? I suppose the problem is with the ending numbers that are different.

Comment: what does `ldd /bin/pgbouncer`  say?  Also,  your binary requires `.so.6`  instead of `.so.7`.